# Why do DC motors draw more (and not less) current when they are stalled?

Tags: dc-motor

I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwFE-NkzR-k) which shows a method of empirically estimating the amperage draw of a DC motor if you only know its voltage. The author of that video shows a multimeter rigged up to read the amps on the motor as its operating under 2 different modes: no load and stalled.

What the video demonstrates is that the DC motor draws less amps when operating under no load than it draws when it is stalled completely. Although it makes sense when you think about, (the motor is straining harder so it likely is drawing more current), I'm not understanding how it relates to the `V = IR` formula.

If the battery voltage (6V) is staying the same, and he's increasing the resistance on the motor so much that it stalls, V stays the same, R goes way high, so I (the amperage) would have to go down, right?

Oversimplified example:

```
V = IR
6volts = 0.03A * 200 ohms

Now we stall the motor, ohms goes to, say, 10K, so:
V = IR
6volts = I * 10,000 ohms
I = 6volts / 10K ohms
I = 0.0006A
```

I know I'm missing *something*, but not seeing the "forest through the trees" here. Can someone help explain where I'm going awry? Thanks!

Comment: Resistance of that example motor is constant near 8 ohms, stalled or free-running. 6V divided by 8 ohms should be very close to stalled current.

Comment: @glen_geek but you need to account for back EMF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mechanical resistance is not the same as electrical resistance. The electrical resistance of the motor's windings doesn't change as it speeds up or slows down. Its back EMF does.

The back EMF is the voltage that the motor generates if you were to operate it as a generator at the speed it's currently running at. This voltage opposes the voltage that you're supplying the motor with, effectively lowering the voltage available to the windings in the motor, and thereby reducing power draw. As the motor spins slower, the back EMF gets lower. Less back EMF means that the motor power increases. When the motor stalls, no back EMF is generated at all, and the motor can draw the maximum possible power (and potentially burn out).

A motor isn't a resistor, so it doesn't necessarily obey Ohm's law. There are different physical phenomena at play (electromagnetism).